# How to call a function in a specific hour with Installable triggers

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to call a function at a specific hour (I know that with installable triggers it's not possible to be specific and they could be activated just within an hour) but I've found a way to do it specifically with a double a function but it seems it doesn't work on my sheet. Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

This is the code:

```
function immutableTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('mutableTrigger')
  .timeBased()
  .everyDays(1)
  .create();
}



function mutableTrigger() {
  const today = new Date();
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const month = today.getMonth();
  const day = today.getDate();
  const functionName = '_7Amnuevo';
  
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
    trigger.getHandlerFunction() === functionName ? ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger) : 0;
  });

  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
  .timeBased()
  .at(new Date(year, month, day, 17, 0))
  .create();
}

function _7Amnuevo() {
  }
```

Basically, I would like to change the "Query" in my sheet "from B=4 to B=5" (I've made the Function _7Amnuevo for this) in order to change the people who appear in that formula so, I would like to call the _7Am function at 5:00 pm or another specific hour.

To have a clearer idea of what I am trying to do, I leave my sheet here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Vnfx7zV8kGkHWLaHMhewvQjg6AASMc4iMnrW3w8WTo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide more details about what is the expected result and what you got. P.S. While a link to an external resource might be helpful, please bear in mind that all the relevant details should be included directly in the question body.

Comment: I think JavaScript function names have to start with a letter

Comment: Kindly use a descriptive title as mentioned in [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
function mutableTrigger() {
  const today = new Date();
  const year = today.getFullYear();
  const month = today.getMonth();
  const day = today.getDate();
  const functionName = 'Amnuevo';

  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.getHandlerFunction() === functionName) {
      ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(trigger);
    }
  });
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)
    .timeBased()
    .at(new Date(year, month, day, 17, 0))
    .create();
}

function Amnuevo() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("I am here");
}
```

Comment: Awesome Cooper! it works! thank you so much! I had a hard time with this but this code works great.